# How to Count the number of distinct keys in a dictionary in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

The numbers are **serial number** and the dictionary belongs to that serial number is data. I want to count the length of  dictionary belong to distinct serial number in django template.
The name of dictionary is redict.

```
{15: [<videoscomment: Reply...byNavneetKaur>, <videoscomment: Reply...byNavneetKaur>], 20: [<videoscomment: 2nd comment reply...byNavneetKaur>]}
```

I have tried the following methods

comments.sno is the number and below gets data belong to that number

```
redict|get_val:comments.sno
```

and i put count in the last to get the length of data.

```
redict|get_val:comments.sno.count
```

And remember we have to do that in django template.

Comment: May I know why you want to do that on the template ?  It is always advisable to do the business logic in the views than in the templates ??

Comment: Because i have arranged all things according to it. So cannot waste my time by again doing all that things.I will be very thankful to you if you solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry , I am not used to the way you are asking... But if updating a lot of stuff is your only problem, then please note that performing this operation in views will take only one line of code. Let me know if you want are ok with that way

Comment: Okk, i can try. You can tell me about that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** If you are familiar with annotations :

```
querysetname = Model.objects.all().annotate(Count('The_Distinct_Field_REQD', 
                                         distinct=True))
```

Or creating a set of the queryset will give only distinct elements since Sets do not allow duplicate values,

```
queryset = already_created_queryset
distinct_count = set(queryset).count() //add this line alone
```

or

```
distinct_count = Model.objects.all(filter as per your condition).distinct('field1',...'n_fields').count()
```

**2** Pass the calculated distinct count through the context dictionary :

```
context = {
    'dist_count' : distinct_count
}
```

**3** Use the dist_count in the template